# Вопрос про файл QRC

Tags: python, qss, pyside, qrc

Поместил файл **QSS** в ресурсы. Получился такой файл **QRC**:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="sun">
    <file>icons/sun-black.svg</file>
    <file>icons/sun-white.svg</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource prefix="styles">
    <file>dark.qss</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource prefix="other">
    <file>icons/arrow_black.png</file>
    <file>icons/arrow_white.png</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource prefix="header">
    <file>icons/expand_black.png</file>
    <file>icons/expand_white.png</file>
    <file>icons/fullscreen_black.png</file>
    <file>icons/fullscreen_white.png</file>
    <file>icons/-black.svg</file>
    <file>icons/-white.svg</file>
    <file>icons/xblack.svg</file>
    <file>icons/xwhite.svg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

После этого конвертировал в **.py**

Вопрос, могу ли я обратиться к файлу **QSS** и использовать его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочее решение:

```
def qss_reader(theme):
    file = QFile(f":styles/{theme}.qss")
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
    styles = file.readAll().data().decode('utf-8')
    file.close()
    return styles
```